# Non Gui Jmeter Test does not stop

Tags: jmeter, video-streaming, performance-testing, load-testing

[image]
I created the following Test Scenario under Ubuntu:

- Thread 100 Vus
- Ram-Up Period Time:400s
- Loop:1
- BZM-Streaming Sampler (video Duration:12seconds)
- Jmeter Version:5.2.1

I configure the Heap Size on the file named jmeter under bin Folder:

- : "${HEAP:="-Xms8192m -Xmx8192m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"}"

the amazing is when I change the Video Streaming Duration to 6 seconds instead of 12 seconds the test works.
I mean every audio and video segment takes 2 seconds approximtatively, so I come to this operation:

- 100 Vus * 6 seconds = 600s / 60minutes = 10 minutes (the whole test takes 22 minutes).

why the test doesn't stop with a Video duration of 12 seconds? I mean the duration is too short for the test!!

What did I miss here... are the Heap size not configured correctly? what is wrong here? in the log I have no java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Issue

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't provide sufficient information so we cannot come up with at least a guess, going forward you will need to provide the following essential information:

1. Is it [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) or [MPEG-DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP)
2. Your playlist URL
3. The relevant parts of [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), pay attention to any `Problem downloading .... segment` warnings. You may need to increase logging verbosity by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming" level="debug"/>
   ```
4. Your streaming sampler full configuration

In any case make sure to use the latest version of the plugin ([HLS Plugin 3.0 has been released recently](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/HLS-3.0-Release/)), you can always upgrade to the most recent version using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Also be aware that you can reach out to JMeter Plugins developers and/or maintainers at [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins).

Comment: playlist URL: https://damxdcfpo.maxdome.de/mxd-manifest-service/mxd-mediavault-prod/6e10a2_99103_2017-08-21_01-52/99103.ism/.mpd?session_id=1007560909-1171280603-6a06f&filter=(type==%22video%22%26%26MaxHeight%3C=576)%7C%7C(type==%22audio%22%26%26FourCC==%22AACL%22)

Comment: it is an HLS Protocol....I've increased the logging verbosity....I use the HLS Pluging 3.0 Version

Comment: see image for streaming sampler full configuration

Comment: ```com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.core.exception.PlaylistDownloadException: Problem downloading master https://damxdcfpo.maxdome.de/mxd-manifest-service/mxd-mediavault-prod/540e30_18928950_2017-08-09_02-49/18928950.ism/.mpd?session_id=1007560909-1171436075-ddb54&filter=(type==%22video%22%26%26MaxHeight%3C=576)%7C%7C(type==%22audio%22%26%26FourCC==%22AACL%22)
```